# For some routes I get "The payload is invalid" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following routes in `web.php`, the first five routes are working perfectly but from `contacts` to `about`routes` fail with the following exception:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException The payload is invalid.

```
Route::get('services', 'PageController@services')->name('services');
Route::get('/service/{id}', 'PageController@showService')->name('service');
Route::get('/blogs', 'PageController@showBlogs')->name('blogs');
Route::get('/{blog}', 'PageController@showPost')->name('post.show');
Route::post('/comment/{blog}/store', 'PageController@storeComment')->name('comment.store');

Route::get('/contacts', 'PageController@contacts')->name('contacts');
Route::post('/contact/store', 'PageController@storeContact')->name('contact.store');
Route::get('/courses', 'PageController@showCourses')->name('courses');
Route::get('/{course}', 'PageController@categoryCourses')->name('course.category');
Route::get('coursesdetail', 'PageController@showCoursesDetail')->name('coursesdetail');
Route::get('resource', 'PageController@showResource')->name('resource');
Route::get('about', 'PageController@showAbout')->name('about');
```

> PageController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use App\About;
use App\Team;
use App\Service;
use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\Tag;
use App\Slider;
use App\Contact;
use App\Client;
use App\Comment;
use App\Course;
use App\Coursecategory;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $about = About::all();
        $teams = Team::all();
        $services = Service::all();
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
        $sliders = Slider::all();
        $clients = Client::all();
        return view('index')->with('about', $about)
            ->with('teams', $teams)
            ->with('services', $services)
            ->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('sliders', $sliders)
            ->with('clients', $clients);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function services()
    {
        $services = Service::all();
        return view('service')->with('services', $services);
    }


    public function showService($id)
    {
        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
        $service = Service::find($id);

        $services = Service::all();
        return view('service')->with('service', $service)->with('services', $services);
    }

    public function showBlogs()
    {
        // $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
        // $recents = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();

        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
        $recents = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(4)->get();

        // $posts = Post::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('blogs')->with('tags', $tags)
            ->with('categories', $categories)
            ->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('recents', $recents);
    }

    public function showPost(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
        $posts = [Post::find($id)];
        $recents = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(4)->get();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $categories = Category::all();
        // $next_id = Post::where('id', '>', $id)->min('id');
        // $prev_id = Post::where('id', '<', $id)->max('id');

        // dd($posts);
        return view('post')->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('recents', $recents)
            ->with('tags', $tags)
            ->with('categories', $categories);
        // ->with('next', Post::find($next_id))
        // ->with('prev', Post::find($prev_id));
    }

    public function storeComment(Request $request, $post)
    {

        request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $contact = Comment::create([
            'post_id' => $post,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'comment' => $request->comments,
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Comment successfully submitted');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function contacts()
    {

        return view('contact');
    }

    public function storeContact(Request $request)
    {

        request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $contact = Contact::create([

            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'comment' => $request->comments,
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Contact information successfully submitted');

        return redirect()->route('contact');
    }

    public function showCourses()
    {

        $categories = Coursecategory::all();
        $courses = Course::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
        return view('courses')->with('courses', $courses)
            ->with('categories', $categories);

    }

    public function categoryCourses($id)
    {
        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
        $course = Coursecategory::where('id', $id)->first()->courses;


        $categories = Coursecategory::all();
        return view('coursewithcategory')->with('course', $course)
            ->with('categories', $categories);
    }

    public function showCoursesDetail()
    {
        return view('coursesdetail');
    }

    public function showResource()
    {
        return view('resource');
    }

    public function showAbout()
    {
        $about = About::all();
        return view('about')->with('about', $about);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please can you add your `PageController` code.

Comment: I add my PageController .php   .

Comment: try to run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: You need to check what value you're passing to `decrypt($id)` method. Is the `$id` correct?

Comment: I run this command, here all routes have shown perfectly but the problem still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the order your routes when you use `uri` as `slug`.

```
Route::get('/contacts', 'PageController@contacts')->name('contacts');
Route::post('/contact/store', 'PageController@storeContact')->name('contact.store');
Route::get('/courses', 'PageController@showCourses')->name('courses');
Route::get('coursesdetail', 'PageController@showCoursesDetail')->name('coursesdetail');
Route::get('resource', 'PageController@showResource')->name('resource');
Route::get('about', 'PageController@showAbout')->name('about');
Route::get('/{course}', 'PageController@categoryCourses')->name('course.category');
```

Comment: Please can you explain why the routes should be in this order.

Comment: @Rwd my bad.`{course}` should be last route, because if `{course}` is in between it will create problem for it`s next routes.